# Unity: Animation With Motion Now running in place

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

I am new to unity.  I am trying to assemble a character that walks forward, stops, and walks forward again when I maneuver the joystick (ps4 controller) accordingly.

I have the whole thing pretty much set up...

However, my animations broke at some point.  Initially, when I added the animations to my character, the character moved with the animation according to the motion encoded in the animations (all of which were auto-rigged at Mixamo...so I am almost certain the bug is downstream in something I did or enabled somehow).

Now, every animation has the character running, turning, jumping etc. in place. Meanwhile, the animation subscreen (when I inspect the clip) shows the character running forward.   I tried implementing some fixes I found online;  I changed the root motion node to Root Transform, for instance...and that is when the most confusing thing happened: a few of the animations started working...but all of the animations showed the character running in place in the subscreen...so now I have no idea what is happening.

Additionally, the animation clips which do not move the character actually transform the character back to the starting position (actually, that isn't correct--I moved the character into the air to test this; the clips without motion transform the character back to the starting position on the ground).

I have disabled all scripts...so have I somehow broken the animations...??? Re-Importing the animations does not fix them either.

---

Here are the images of my character settings, then the controller, and then an animation clip which shows the character moving forward in the sub-clip and where motion information is clearly present...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think this question goes better on game development stack exchange.

Comment: done, thanks--didn't know that stack exchange existed

Comment: I couldn't read that from the text: did you try to turn on Apply Root Motion in the Animator Component? (It is turned off in your options, and your descriptions sounds like it was turned on initially)

Comment: @xyLe_ I did not turn it on initially.  I tried later while debugging...but then I found out that it would produce the same behavior on its own, so I turned it off again...